# Skip a line using BufferedReader (skip, but not read it)

Tags: java, file, file-io, bufferedreader

Hi guys I am currently using `BufferedReader` to read files. I have something like:

```
br.readLine() != null
```

for each call loop.

And now what should I do if I want to skip a line. Here, I've read several similar questions other people posted, most of them suggested using `readLine()`.

I know calling `readLine()` once will cause the pointer to the next line. But this is not preferred as I am considering the reading performance here. Although you seem to skip a line, the system actually read it already, so it is not time-efficiency. What I want is to move the pointer to the next line, without reading it.

Any good idea?

Comment: Also, any good suggestions for skipping without using the BufferedReader is appreciated! And

Comment: You can't just "skip" a line with `BufferedReader` it needs to read the data to find where the line ends.

Comment: Why do you need to skip a line? May be you have other options than `BufferedReader`

Comment: @Kayaman: the question is reasonable. Suppose you have a 10 megabytes till the next `'\n'` character. The `readLine()` method will read all of them into memory just to discard after that.

Comment: Actually I am reading multiple csv files in columnar form. The thing is I just read one column, I only need to retrieve the whole record if and only if that value in this column satisfy some conditions. Otherwise, I trigger the pointer(in other files) to skip.

Comment: "Skip the line" means reading the file contents until you see "new line" marker. Therefore you cannot skip the line without reading. The only thing you may save on is allocating and filling a `String`. Is that enough of savings to worry about? If you must have that, use read() and look for `\n` or some such.

Comment: @TagirValeev I didn't say the question is unreasonable. But I have a hunch that the OP is trying to prematurely optimize something that isn't very significant.

Comment: you can't tell how it tastes without tasting it. You can't tell if a lines empty without reading it. simple!

Comment: Have you looked for some low- lever solution? I suppose combining byte- level opeartions together with search algorithms (e.g. binary search tree) might result in finding more computation- efficient solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you care about the memory wasted in the intermediate `StringBuffer`, you can try the following implementation:

```
public static void skipLine(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
    while(true) {
        int c = br.read();
        if(c == -1 || c == '\n')
            return;
        if(c == '\r') {
            br.mark(1);
            c = br.read();
            if(c != '\n')
                br.reset();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Seems that it works nicely for all the EOLs supported by `readLine` (`'\n'`, `'\r'`, `'\r\n'`).

As an alternative you may extend the `BufferedReader` class adding this method as instance method inside it.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to skip the line without reading it.

In order to know where to skip to, you have to know where the next new line character is, so you have to read it.

P.S. Unless you have a good reason not to, BufferedReader should be fine for you - it's quite efficient

Answer (score 1):

You'll sometimes have a problem skipping the first line with code analysis tools (sonar etc), complaining that you didn't use the value.  In the case of CSV, you may want to skip (i.e. not use) the first row if its headers.  In which case, you could stream the lines and skip perhaps?

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
  Stream<String> lines = reader.lines().skip(1);

  lines.forEachOrdered(line -> {

  ...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's not possible in any language and with any API.

To skip a line you need to know the next line's offset. Either you have a file format that provides you that information, you are given line offsets as input, or you need to read every single byte just to know when a line ends and the next begins.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the code of readLine()? It reads chars one by one until it finds an \r or a \n and appends them to a StringBuffer. What you want is this behaviour without the burden of creating a StringBuffer. Just override the class BufferedReader and provide your own implementation which juste reads chars until /r or /n without building the useless String.

The only problem I see is that many fields are private...